# Remove Excel sheet from background process immediately after data is fetched

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am using below code to release the excel sheet from memory but after the code has run the excel sheet is still in the background. Please help...

public void loadSheet(bool export, string projectName)
        {

```
        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        int rCnt = 0;           
            {

            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:/try/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M.d.yyyy")+@"/"+ projectName+ ".xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, true, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Upload Data"];
            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            totalt.Text = range.Rows.Count.ToString();
            currentID.Text = (range.Rows.Count+1).ToString();  
          Excel.Range).Value2;              

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }

    }

private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                MessageBox.Show("Released"+obj.ToString());
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
```

I want the excel sheet removed from the background after I have fetched the required data from it.

Comment: can you paste all code used interop excel?

p.s. It's a typical problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17367570/976231

Comment: Please check the code

Comment: what does mean `Excel.Range).Value2;`. this code not compiled

Answer (score 1):

Such double-dot-calling expressions:

```
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(/*args*/);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Upload Data"];
```

you should replace with

```
var workbooks = excel.Workbooks;
xlWorkBook  = workbooks.Open(/*params*/)
var worksheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
xlWorkSheet = worksheets["Upload Data"];

//business logic here

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);    
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
```

for more info, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17367570/976231

**upd**:

```
xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        int rCnt = 0;           
            {

            var workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks;
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:/try/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M.d.yyyy")+@"/"+ projectName+ ".xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, true, 0, true, 1, 0);
            var worksheets = xlWorkBook.Worksheets;
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Upload Data"];
            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            var rows = range.Rows;
            totalt.Text = rows.Count.ToString();
            currentID.Text = (rows.Count + 1).ToString();               

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            xlApp.Quit();


            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rows);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheets);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbooks);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        }

    }
```

Comment: tried but it doent seems to work. Can you please change the above code which i gave.. and help i did

Comment: `Excel.Workbooks a = xlApp.Workbooks;
            xlWorkBook = a.Open("E:\\try\\CL.xlsx", 0, false, 5 , "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);`

Comment: and then releaseObject(a) was added at last still it doent works