# How to get handle on an open excel file in vb.net with .net 8.0.2.?

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using vb.net and .net 8.0.2. App is running on Windows 11.
I have been trying for hours to point to an excel file which has already been opened by the user.

I tried:

```
Dim app_excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

 app_excel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 wbk  = app_excel.Workbooks("filename.xlsx")
```

which doesn't work, oXL is creating a new Excel app, and wbk is empty.

I also tried:

```
  app_excel = CType(System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
  wbk  = app_excel.Workbooks("filename.xlsx")
```

but I get a IDE error saying that GetActiveObject is not a member of Marshal.
Apparently Marshal has been rebuilt in latest version of .net GetActiveObject doesn't exist anymore.
I saw some resources saying that they had to entirely rebuild the Marshal so I built the Marshal2 class following in C# as explained here:
[No definition found for GetActiveObject from System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010510/no-definition-found-for-getactiveobject-from-system-runtime-interopservices-mars)

and used it in my code as such:

```
Dim ExcelInstance As Excel.Application = ProjectMarshal.Marshal2.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
wkb_configFile = ExcelInstance.Workbooks("configuration.xlsm")
```

which does compile but I get an error at Execution with "invalid Index".
When I check with the watch window there doesn't seem to be any workbook within ExcelInstance though the file is opened.

if I replaced the 3rd line with:

```
wkb_configFile = ExcelInstance.Workbooks(1)
```

I get wkb_configFile = "Book1" which is most likely the workbook opened by default when Excel starts. ExcelInstance.Workbooks(2) doesn't exist (while there are 2 files opened).

Edit 22/MAR:
with the help of community members and in particular user246821 I came to the conclusion that targetting .net framework (4.8) for the project instead of .net 8.0 was a better alternative. It does seem to work with the standard GetObject(, "Excel.Application") method.
However, now I get runs where the file is still not found despite being opened. I suspect it could be because other excel files are opened, and each excel makes a separate instance of an excel application in the code.
I added a check on all excel instances to find the right workbook:

```
Dim ExcelInstances As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL") 
Dim instance As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application'EXCEL 
For Each instance In ExcelInstances
   'If app_excel.Workbooks(s_pathToFileToOpen) IsNot Nothing Then
   If instance.Workbooks("configuration.xlsx") IsNot Nothing Then
     fun_isFileOpened = True
     Exit Function
   End If
   Debug.WriteLine($"ExcelInstances: ProcessName: {instance.ProcessName} Id: {instance.Id}")
Next
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `oXL = New Excel.Application`  why is that there? You are already using `GetObject`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010510/no-definition-found-for-getactiveobject-from-system-runtime-interopservices-mars

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72832357/10024425

Comment: @Charlieface you are right, I will update the code here, with just a declaration of excel app.

Comment: @hans passant this answer in C#. I have tried to re-code but I didn't managed. I think this is beyond my skill set at the moment, especially this part:
'''
 [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical] 
'''

Comment: @user246821 thanks but this is the same code, which leads to the issue mentioned above. Marshal.GetActiveObject doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Lots of C# to vb.net converters out there.  But really, .NET excels at handling different programming languages.  So just put it in a C# class library.

Comment: @HansPassant ah haven't thought about it. Will try that then! thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant I tried still without success. Excel finds only one workbook: the default one when starting excel.

Comment: The code in the post that you [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496277/10024425) works if one uses it correctly. See [How to use Visual C# to automate a running instance of an Office program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/use-visual-c-automate-run-program-instance) (look for the line that says *System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker*).

Comment: @user246821 the page you reference has code (written in 2021) that uses .Marshal.GetActiveObject which is deprecated since last year. How would it work? 
However I will try bindToMoniker which seems to still be present (I already did without success but will try again).

Comment: Use the code that you found for _Marshal2_ in that line instead. Why have you chosen to use [.NET 8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)? Support for _.NET 8_ ends in 2026. Your life would be easier if you used [.NETFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) which is currently supported and doesn't have an end-of-support date.

Comment: @user246821 good to know! I didn't chose, Visual Studio gave it as default value and I had no clue which one was the best. I will try to switch!

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76416772/10024425

Comment: @user246821 so I re-built the project using .net framework 4.8 and still no luck, the file configuration.xlsm cannot be found while it is opened: 

`app_excel = TryCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)`
`wkb_configFile = app_excel.Workbooks(CONFIGURATION_FILENAME)`

raise an error at execution.

Comment: Enable [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) and [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) for your project. Then you'll be required to declare your variables. Ensure that you also declare data types.

Comment: Did you try using _System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker_? The file name needs to be fully-qualified. (ex: C:\Users\John Smith\Documents\Book1.xlsx). This assumes that the Excel workbook was previously saved. If the workbook is a newly created workbook that hasn't been saved, then one would use _Book1_ (no file extension).

Comment: It finally worked ! 
The right code was indeed: 

 `wkb_configFile = Marshal.BindToMoniker(s_pathToConfigFile)`
with s_pathToConFile = "C:\Configuration.xlsm"

Thanks so much for your help @user246821 !!

Now trying to make sure it doesn't open the file but find the one already opened ...

Comment: @user246821 i was too fast. It seems bind to moniker always find the file and return the object, even if not opened.... 

still haven't figured out how to solve that... would be great that my question would not have been closed so fast by the moderator btw, now we can only use the comments to respond.

Latest code: 
`wkb_configFile = Marshal.BindToMoniker(s_pathToConfigFile)
If wkb_configFile Is Nothing Then
   (open file)
 End If`

Answer (score 0):

The following show how to interact with an open Excel workbook using a VB.NET (.NETFramework) project. When working with [Component Object Model (COM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal), it's important for one to release the COM objects when finished with them. When using Visual Studio debugger and an exception is thrown, it's possible that the COM objects may not be released and the *Microsoft Excel* process remains running in the background - even after closing *Microsoft Excel*. One can verify this by opening *Task Manager* (ie: press *Ctrl-Alt-Del* ) and look under *Background processes* for *Microsoft Excel*. In the code below, this situation is detected and the orphaned process is terminated.

**Note**: While the code below seems to work, it has had limited testing which means that one should test it to ensure that it behaves as desired.

Try the following:

```
Public Sub UpdateExcel(value As String, fileMonikerName As String)

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
    Dim desiredWb As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

    Try
        Dim ExcelProcesses() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")

        If ExcelProcesses.Count() = 0 Then
            Debug.WriteLine("Info: No Excel processes found.")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        For Each p As Process In ExcelProcesses
            Debug.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} - p.Id: {p.Id} p.MainWindowHandle: {p.MainWindowHandle.ToString("X8")}")

            If p.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
                'an exception in this method may cause Excel to remain running in
                'the background even after both this program and Excel have been closed
                'if the Excel process is valid p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero
                'however, if the Excel process has been orphaned, then p.MainWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero
                'and the 'Microsoft Excel' process can be observed in Task Manager under 'Background processes'
                'kill orphaned Excel process
                p.Kill()

                Debug.WriteLine("Info: An orphaned Excel process was terminated, but no active Excel instances were found. Open desired Excel workbook and try again.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next

        'get existing Excel instance
        excelApp = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)

        'prevent prompting to save
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

        'ensure Excel is visible
        excelApp.Visible = True

        'get desired workbook

        For Each workbook As Excel.Workbook In excelApp.Workbooks
            Debug.WriteLine($"               wb FullName: '{workbook.FullName}' Name: '{workbook.Name}'")

            If fileMonikerName = workbook.FullName Then
                'set value
                desiredWb = workbook

                For Each worksheet As Excel.Worksheet In desiredWb.Sheets
                    Debug.WriteLine($"               ws Name: '{worksheet.Name}'")

                    'ToDo: select desired worksheet
                    'set value
                    ws = worksheet

                    'activate worksheet
                    ws.Activate()
                Next
            End If
        Next

        If desiredWb Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception($"Error: Desired workbook not found ('{fileMonikerName}').")
        End If

        If ws Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Error: Worksheet not found.")
        End If

        'set value - for A1 also known as 1,1

        'format column to display date
        ws.Cells().Range("A1", "A4").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"

        'set value
        ws.Cells(1, 1) = $"{DateTime.Now.ToOADate()}"
        ws.Cells(1, 2) = value

        'save
        desiredWb.SaveAs(fileMonikerName, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)

    Finally

        If ws IsNot Nothing Then
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ws)
            ws = Nothing
        End If

        If desiredWb IsNot Nothing Then
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(desiredWb)
            desiredWb = Nothing
        End If

        If excelApp IsNot Nothing Then
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp)
            excelApp = Nothing

            GC.Collect()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

**Usage**:

```
Using ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    ofd.Filter = "Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"

    If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        UpdateExcel($"Test {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}", ofd.FileName)
    End If
End Using
```

**Resources:**

- [VB.Net Add Workbook to Running EXCEL Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74306169/10024425)
- [Get Excel Active Worksheet with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72832357/10024425)