Is there a way to update an excel file from a. Net 8 application and view the changes live in excel
I'm currently working on a .NET 8 project that requires updating (on key input) an excel sheet whilst the file is open in excel. For simplicity's sake here's an easy example the file is open in excel and when I press space bar turn column green. I'm currently using a nuget package called EPPlus which is great but doesn't support the live update I'm looking for. Is there any nuget package or a method that I could use to implement this functionality?
I have searched for other nuget's but none I have found will allow me this functionality.

You're assuming that the Excel application itself will reload it's view when the file it has opened has been modified.

Have you looked at the office interop assemblies provided by Microsoft? They provide functionality for working directly with Office applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interop/walkthrough-office-programming

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78208187/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496277/10024425.

Not really; Excel doesn't play nice with other applications regards opening excel files in a shared mode. If you attempt to open a file Excel is already showing your application gets an error because excel locks the file. Perhaps you can convince an excel macro to download data from a rest api you host, so that Excel hits your API, gets told "change cell A1 to value "abc", it makes the change, and then your api causes "live" changes by varying what it tells Excel to do. Tbh it would be easier to build something else, like a Blazor app that does all your nice dynamism
