# How to properly close Excel in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I searched and tried several different approaches, but none seems to properly close Excel.

There always remain a zombie Excel process that I have to kill it manually.

I have no problem with Word, only with Excel.

```
excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
while (excel.Workbooks.Count > 0)
  excel.Workbooks[1].Close(SaveChanges: false);
excel.Quit();
```

I also tried with:

```
int rc = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
while (rc > 0)
  rc = Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
_ = Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excel);
```

Either way the zombie Excel process remains.

How can I properly close it?

Edited to add:

It was pointed that this question might be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367411/cannot-close-excel-exe-after-interop-process) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134024/clean-up-excel-interop-objects-with-idisposable). However, in my searches I did find those two questions (amongst many others) and none of their answers solve the problem.

Comment: Your code doesn’t reflect what is said here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134024/clean-up-excel-interop-objects-with-idisposable - so did you try it?

Comment: I personally like this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38111294/2598770