# Is this programming pattern the solution to Excel COM interop memory leaks?

Tags: c#, com, vsto, com-interop, excel-interop

I don’t wish to contribute to the mysticism of this subject further than it already seems to be on internet. I’ve many articles talking about this subject, some say never Marshal.ReleaseComObject anything, there’s the “2-dot rule”, yada yada.
The fact is, my Excel VSTO addin does slow down and crash after prolonged use, and I don’t call ReleaseComObject all the time. I’ve also measured (through a timer) a drastic performance hit when summoning another COM object into existence through one’s property (e.g. hyperlink.Name returns instantly, hyperlink.Range.Address returns approx. 214 times slower) which intuitively suggest that said COM object must/should have Marshal.ReleaseComObject called upon it since .NET’s GC won’t collect it (it’d only the RCW, not the underlying COM object).
With all this out of the way, do you think interfacing with Excel interop through a set of wrapper classes of the following pattern would allow .NET’s native GC to actually take care of all memory management once again? Please do not point out the amount of coding effort necessary to make this work (I don’t care, if it makes my program not slow down and crash, I’ll do it).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using IRibbon = Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility;
using App = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application;
using Wbs = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks;
using Wb = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook;
using Shs = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets;
using Ws = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
using Table = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject;
using Row = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListRow;
using Column = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListColumn;
using Cells = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
using Name = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name;
using Chart = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Chart;
using Shape = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Office.ExcelUtilities
{
    public class ApplicationWrapper
    {
        App _app;
        public ApplicationWrapper(App app)
        {
            _app = app;
        }
        public WorkbookWrapper AddWorkbook()
        {
            Wbs wbs = _app.Workbooks;
            Wb wb = wbs.Add();
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbs);
            return new WorkbookWrapper(wb);
        }
        ~ApplicationWrapper()
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_app);
        }
    }
    public class WorkbookWrapper
    {
        Wb _wb = null;
        internal WorkbookWrapper(Wb wb)
        {
            _wb = wb;
        }
        public WorkbookWrapper()
        {
            //just lets client hold this object
            if(_wb == null )
                throw new Exception("You didn't create a workbook right");
        }
        public WorksheetWrapper AddWorksheet(string sheetName)
        {
            Shs wss = _wb.Worksheets;
            Ws ws = wss.Add();
            ws.Name = sheetName;
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wss);
            return new WorksheetWrapper(ws);
        }
        ~WorkbookWrapper()
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_wb);
        }
    }
    public class WorksheetWrapper
    {
        Ws _ws = null;
        internal WorksheetWrapper(Ws ws)
        {
            _ws = ws;
        }
        public WorksheetWrapper()
        {
            //just lets client hold this object
            if(_ws == null)
                throw new Exception("You didn't create a worksheet right");
        }
        ~WorksheetWrapper()
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_ws);
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously not complete, but you get the idea. Please excuse my renaming of base interop types.
Thanks!

Comment: No.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17367570 .  In `AddWorksheet`, the reference obtained by `_wb.Worksheets` before calling `Add` isn't explicitly released. You can't rely on the GC to dispose the RCW at any specific time (and the GC does not attempt to dispose things at termination in .NET Core/5+), so you can very easily leak references and prevent shutdown of the application.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot close Excel.exe after Interop process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367411/cannot-close-excel-exe-after-interop-process)

Comment: @madreflection Good catch. I modified the code so that it captures the Worksheets object, uses it, then releases it (same for Worksheets).
Would it work good now?

Comment: There's no memory leaks in Excel, COM or .NET as such, but you must understand how .NET works with COM, read Hans' message here and make sure you understand 100% of what he says https://stackoverflow.com/a/25135685/403671 Also, the performance hit you may see is totally unrelated to references, it's (probably) related to what is transfered between your code and Excel, (if it's out of process you must also understand what's transferred, there may be huge arrays)

Comment: That's better, but if `Add` throws an exception, `wss` doesn't released right away (deferred to GC/disposal). So you need a try/finally on that.  It's not looking much like a "pattern" due to how much manual work you're having to do.

Comment: @SimonMourier I've read Hans' message and I don't think it's relevant to my situation. I'm never trying to close Excel, I have an Excel VSTO addin running that crashes after heavy use, unpredictably. I'm looping several thousand COM objs which in turn summon more COM objs from their properties and not calling marshal release on them all the time.

Comment: @madreflection That's fair, `Add` could throw an exception which makes it not release. Coding "pattern" might not be the right word sure. Ignoring how much work this is, sounds like coding in this style might not even fix memory issues because we do not know if and when those Finalizers would kick in and call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`? Does `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` force it to do so then?

Comment: What I did (and I can make this an answer if it sounds good enough), is to create a helper that accesses the property via lambda and wraps it in my own disposable to use in a `using` block, with an output for the actual object reference that's local to that block. The `using` block disposes the wrapping `IDisposable` object, which calls `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`.

Comment: It creates structure around the use of each object. You don't have to think about when to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` because it gets called when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: @madreflection The problem is that my addin has some class objects which in turn have properties of Excel COM interop types, that it keeps alive during the lifetime of the program. When I blindly call `Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject` on the objs right after I have done using them, I end of often releasing the COM object that was a property of my living class! Then I get the whole 'underlying COM object seperated' error.
So what do you suggest to that?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you're releasing something that you shouldn't. References in COM are only *counted*, so `Marshal.RelaseComObject` twice on the same object is perfectly valid (and so there's no protection against it) if you acquired another reference, e.g., by calling `AddRef`. But if you didn't do that, you'd be decrementing the count more times than you have the right to do.

Comment: It would help if you showed how you're using both the references that you have for the lifetime of the program and the ones that are short-lived.

Comment: @madreflection Releasing something I shouldn't is exactly what's happening and is my problem. I didn't frame this post/question very well to target the root issue. I'll post something new tomorrow with a code example and link you to it. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's relevant, your questions about 2.dot rule shows that you don't really understand what Hans said. Addin or not, it doesn't change the overall principles. There's no need to retain and release each object, the GC will do it. If you really see memory grow to the sky because you allocate millions in 1 second say (thousands is nothing) and you need that memory back, then can call GC.Collect() GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() sometimes but it's optional. The crashes are something very different that need to be looked at, but not related to object references.

Comment: @SimonMourier User's of my Excel addin are having the issue that it becomes sluggish after prolonged use. When I look at their memory usage for EXCEL.EXE, it's enormously high, and they obtain high speed again when they close Excel as the memory usage is low again. Are you suggesting simply adding `GC.Collect()` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` at the end of every user interface function would make their memory usage not become enormous?

Comment: Reread Hans' answer "What matters a great deal however is exactly where you put this code [etc.]". It depends on your code, basically when you think you have probably done quite a lot of work with Excel object model. If after calling this, memory doesn't reduce, it means the memory problem comes from elsewhere (for example if you use static dictionaries/lists/arrays their content will never get collected), or other issues (like buggy interop call), etc

Answer (score 1):

> since .NET’s GC won’t collect it (it’d only the RCW, not the
> underlying COM object).

Not true - GC **will** release the COM object, you just have no say over when that happens. When RCW object is disposed, it will `Release()` the underlying COM object, and if nothing else holds a reference to it (ref count == 0), the COM object will destroy itself.

`Marshal.ReleaseComObject` and multiple dot rule are only really needed in very special cases, when you want full control over the order and timing of COM object releases. E.g., if you have a loop over all items in an Outlook folder and access hundreds or thousands of items, especially if Outlook is in online mode, which limits the number of open RPC connections to the Exchange Server.

In your particular case, I doubt it will make any difference at all.

Comment: [*"A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run."*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203) - When dealing with out-of-process COM servers (like all Office applications), the 2-dot rule becomes quite important in that light because it can leave unreleased references that aren't being tracked by a running program.

Comment: I did not include my program I'm writing. It very much does loop over several thousand COM objects, and often will access a property like "topCell.Range.Interior.Font = xxx" where Range, Interior, and Font are all COM objects that aren't marshal released.
So if what you say is true that the GC will collect RCW objects at some point, does marshal release on the object force it to do so immediately? And if so, are my large memory usage issues a result of GC simply not collecting fast enough due to my negligence of  marshal release?

Comment: Given enough time, the GC probably will release all the references, but it's not required to. `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` removes all doubt as to *if* and *when* a reference will be released. I would say yes, your large memory usage issues are the result of the GC waiting to collect those RCWs.

Comment: [*"Garbage collection is simulating a computer with an infinite amount of memory."*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203), so it may not collect anything until it runs out, and even then it doesn't have to collect everything that's unreferenced, only enough to be able to handle the latest allocation request.

Comment: Yes, if you have loops over hundreds or thousands objects, then breaking multiple dot statements and releasing each and every object explicitly is a good idea. If you want to start with minimal changes, try to scope the loops either with `{}` or by putting the code into separate methods and call `GC.Collect()` after the code runs and the objects go out of scope (to be eligible for collection). I'd be apprehensive about using `GC.Collect()` in production code, but if you see better performance and reduced memory footprint, you'll know you are on the right track.